# Akka stream GraphStage is not running the final invocation of an async callback

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, akka-stream

I have been going round in circles, on and off, for weeks on this and I have yet to find an answer so I am hoping that someone with better knowledge of Akka Streams will be able to help.

I have a custom GraphStage that does a load of logic and then calls out to an async process (in fact it materializes a substream to perform a binary data copy from an external service into S3), that looks something like this (simplified):

```scala
class UploadItemShape(shapeNameAnyOf:Seq[String], bucketName:String, cannedAcl:CannedAcl)(implicit comm:VSCommunicator, mat:Materializer)
  extends GraphStage[FlowShape[VSLazyItem, VSLazyItem ]] with FilenameHelpers {

  private final val in:Inlet[VSLazyItem] = Inlet.create("UploadItemShape.in")
  private final val out:Outlet[VSLazyItem] = Outlet.create("UploadItemShape.out")

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
    private implicit val logger:org.slf4j.Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

    private var canComplete:Boolean=true

    setHandler(in, new AbstractInHandler {
      override def onPush(): Unit = {
        val completedCb = createAsyncCallback[VSLazyItem](i=>{
          logger.info(s"called completedCb")
          canComplete=true
          push(out, i)
        })

        val failedCb = createAsyncCallback[Throwable](err=>{
          logger.error("Called failedCallback: ", err)
          canComplete=true
          failStage(err)
        })

        val elem = grab(in)
        canComplete = false

        val shapes = shapeNameAnyOf.map(shapeName=>
          findShape(elem,shapeName)
        ).collect({case Some(s)=>s})

        if(shapes.nonEmpty){
          if(shapes.length>1){
            logger.warn(s"Got shapes multiple shapes $shapes for item ${elem.itemId}, using the first")
          }

          bunchOfFuturesChainedTogetherGivingUploadResult()
          .flatMap(uploadResult=>{
            logger.info(s"Uploaded to ${uploadResult.location}")
            completedCb.invokeWithFeedback(elem)
          }).recoverWith({
            case err:Throwable=>
              logger.error(s"Could not perform upload for any of shape $shapeNameAnyOf on item ${elem.itemId}: ", err)
              failedCb.invokeWithFeedback(err)
          })

        } else {
          val actualShapeNames = elem.shapes.map(_.keySet)
          logger.error(s"No shapes could be found matching $shapeNameAnyOf on the given item (got $actualShapeNames)")
          push(out, elem)
        }
      }

      //override the finish function to ensure that any async procesing has completed before we allow ourselves
      //to shut down
      override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
        var i=0

        logger.info(s"Upstream finished")
        while(!canComplete){
          logger.info(s"Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...")
          i+=1
          if(i>10) canComplete=true
          Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
        logger.info(s"Processing completed")
        completeStage()
      }
    })

    setHandler(out, new AbstractOutHandler {
      override def onPull(): Unit = pull(in)

      override def onDownstreamFinish(): Unit = {
        logger.info("Downstream finished")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I am running it through a test case that looks something like this (again, simplified):

```
      val resultFut = Source
        .single(item)
        .via(testStage)
        .log("streamComponents.UploadItemShape")
        .toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.right)
        .run()

      val result = Await.result(resultFut,30 seconds)
```

where `testStage` is the initialized GraphStage with appropriate parts mocked out with Mockito.

So, when I initially ran it from a Single source as above, my mocks were all called correctly but nothing was emitted at the end (Sink.seq gave me an empty sequence).
I then added the `canComplete` flag and the `onUpstreamFinish` and `onDownstreamFinish` handlers to show what was going on.

It waits until timeout with the "Async processing ongoing" message and I never see the "called completedCb" message.  Then, when the stage completes due to timeout I see "Stage stopped before async invocation was processed"

I then changed the test to push two items into the stage like this:

```
      val resultFut = Source
        .fromIterator(()=>Seq(item,item).toIterator).async
        .via(testStage)
        .log("streamComponents.UploadItemShape")
        .toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.right)
        .run()

      val result = Await.result(resultFut,30 seconds)
```

The logs show that the async callbacks *are* triggered for the first item, just not the last one:

```
12:34:58.152 [scala-execution-context-global-57] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Determined /path/to/somefile.mp4 as the path to upload
12:34:58.153 [scala-execution-context-global-57] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Filename with fixed extension is /path/to/somefile.mp4
12:34:58.192 [scala-execution-context-global-57] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Uploaded to s3://somebucket/path/to/somefile
12:34:58.193 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - called completedCb
12:34:58.195 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Upstream finished
12:34:58.195 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:34:58.195 [scala-execution-context-global-95] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Determined /path/to/somefile.mp4 as the path to upload
12:34:58.196 [scala-execution-context-global-95] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Filename with fixed extension is /path/to/somefile.mp4
12:34:58.197 [scala-execution-context-global-95] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Uploaded to s3://somebucket/path/to/somefile
12:34:59.199 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:00.203 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:01.206 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:02.210 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:03.213 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:04.218 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:05.221 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:06.226 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:07.230 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:08.234 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...
12:35:09.237 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Processing completed
12:35:09.239 [scala-execution-context-global-95] ERROR streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3 - Could not perform upload for any of shape List(lowres, lowaudio, lowimage) on item VX-1234: 
akka.stream.StreamDetachedException: Stage with GraphStageLogic streamComponents.UploadItemShape$$anon$3@10371e38 stopped before async invocation was processed
```

(obviously no real uploads are being performed, the futures are being supplied as Future.complete by Mockito).

It seems that no matter what I do, as soon as the *upstream* has completed (I never saw the "Downstream finished" message) then the stage is unable to process async invocations despite being not completed *and* knowing that they still need to be completed.  I've scoured every piece of documentation I can find, and the source code, but have yet to find anything to help me with this head-scratcher.  Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Custom graph stages with async calls and futures give problems. I would avoid them. Include your async operations as macAsync calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph stages run inside of an actor and can only ever do one thing at a time, this means that if you make it block inside of a method (`Thread.sleep`) it can never do anything else at the same time.

If you want to wait for outstanding async callbacks to arrive you would have to "know" that there is an outstanding future by recording that fact somehow, a counter for example. When onComplete happens you would have to let the stage continue running by *not* calling `completeStage()`, and then make sure to complete the stage once the async callback arrives.

Note that an `AsyncCallback` is something stays resident during the lifetime of the running graph stage after you have created so you should not create one per pushed element but rather create one and re-use that or you will have a memory leak on your hands.

`GraphStage` is a low level API to implement operators requiring quite a bit of detailed understanding of Akka Streams, if all you want is to chain futures I'd recommend you use one of the existing operators handling futures such as `mapAsync` or `mapAsyncUnordered` rather than trying to make your own, they will behave like you want with not completing until all outstanding futures have completed.

Comment: Been a while since I was here, but yes you're right.  I can get around the problem by setting a boolean flag when I start the async operation and clearing it in the invoked asyncCallback.  Then, I use a second boolean flag to indicate that a completion is pending and override onUpstreamFinish() in the In handler to only run completeStage() if there is no pending async. If there is, set the pending completion flag.  Then, in the asyncCallback, if the pending completion flag is set call completeStage().  You're 100% right about the callback lifetime, dunno how that got into the wrong place!

Answer (score 1):

Source of akka-stream on runWith returns a future having success and failure.

```
 val resultFut = Source
        .fromIterator(()=>Seq(item,item).toIterator).async
        .via(testStage)
        .log("streamComponents.UploadItemShape")
        .toMat(Sink.seq)
        .runWith().onComplete {
            case Success(value) => logger.info(s"stream completed successfully $value")
            case Failure(e) => logger.error(s"stream completed with failure: $e")
         }
```

onComplete callback will invoke on completion.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the problem is you have just mapped a function to a future. Mapping will not actually invoke the function until it is triggered or assigned to a value that is utilized else where. The point is that the future is not getting materialized by just mapping it a behaviour or recover.
If you change the flatMap to onComplete and add the respective completeCB to success and failedCB to failure handlers this should work. 
I have implemented something very similar to what is shown in your code and it had worked for me perfectly fine. Please check the modified code.

```
class UploadItemShape(shapeNameAnyOf:Seq[String], bucketName:String, cannedAcl:CannedAcl)(implicit comm:VSCommunicator, mat:Materializer)
  extends GraphStage[FlowShape[VSLazyItem, VSLazyItem ]] with FilenameHelpers {

  private final val in:Inlet[VSLazyItem] = Inlet.create("UploadItemShape.in")
  private final val out:Outlet[VSLazyItem] = Outlet.create("UploadItemShape.out")

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
    private implicit val logger:org.slf4j.Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

    private var canComplete:Boolean=true

    setHandler(in, new AbstractInHandler {
      override def onPush(): Unit = {}

        val elem = grab(in)
        canComplete = false

        val shapes = shapeNameAnyOf.map(shapeName=>
          findShape(elem,shapeName)
        ).collect({case Some(s)=>s})

        if(shapes.nonEmpty){
          if(shapes.length>1){
            logger.warn(s"Got shapes multiple shapes $shapes for item ${elem.itemId}, using the first")
          }

          bunchOfFuturesChainedTogetherGivingUploadResult()
          .onComplete{
            case Success(_) =>
              logger.info(s"called completedCb")
              canComplete=true
              push(out, i)
            case Failure(ex) =>
              logger.error(s"Could not perform upload for any of shape $shapeNameAnyOf on item ${elem.itemId}: ", err)
              canComplete=true
              failStage(err)

          }

        } else {
          val actualShapeNames = elem.shapes.map(_.keySet)
          logger.error(s"No shapes could be found matching $shapeNameAnyOf on the given item (got $actualShapeNames)")
          push(out, elem)
        }
      }

      //override the finish function to ensure that any async procesing has completed before we allow ourselves
      //to shut down
      override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
        var i=0

        logger.info(s"Upstream finished")
        while(!canComplete){
          logger.info(s"Async processing ongoing, waiting for completion...")
          i+=1
          if(i>10) canComplete=true
          Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
        logger.info(s"Processing completed")
        completeStage()
      }
    })

    setHandler(out, new AbstractOutHandler {
      override def onPull(): Unit = pull(in)

      override def onDownstreamFinish(): Unit = {
        logger.info("Downstream finished")
      }
    })
  }
}
```